# fetching data from jsonArray in java

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON Array `JsonArray.toString(0)` whose value is:

```
{
  "html_instructions": "Head <b>west</b> on <b>Park St</b> toward <b>Glenferrie Rd</b>/<b>State Route 19</b>",
  "duration": {
    "value": 40,
    "text": "1 min"
  },
  "distance": {
    "value": 109,
    "text": "0.1 km"
  },
  "end_location": {
    "lng": 145.0358882,
    "lat": -37.8197498
  },
  "polyline": {
    "points": "huyeF}pftZIjAC`@MdC"
  },
  "travel_mode": "DRIVING",
  "start_location": {
    "lng": 145.0371141,
    "lat": -37.8198945
  }
}
```

how can I extract only the first element from this? ie. "html_instructions".

Comment: this seems straight forward, what did you try?

Comment: I tried JsonArray.getJSONObject("html_instructions") but it gives me an error saying that it's expecting the parameter to be a string.

Comment: that's a json object not array

Comment: and is html_instruction an object?

Comment: the json you have posted is an object not an array

Comment: okay, but how do only extract the first element. plz give me some more insight

Answer (score 0):

You need to first get JSON object of 0th index then only you can find that element.

Try this:

```
jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).get("html_instruction")
```